# Max count of items in comma-delimited IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A simple question, but I think it deserves it's place out here for an answer.

I have a T-SQL statement:

```
select Name
from MyTable
where ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,.....)
```

How many comma-delimited IDs can I put in this select before SQL breaks? Will it break?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum length of the list is only restricted by the maximum batch size which is 65536 network packets. A network packet is 4 KB by default. So that makes about 268 MB of T-SQL text. If you take an average length of 10 digits per element including the separating `,` you can put about 25 million separate values in there still leaving room for the rest of the query.

See: [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Comment: Of course, 25 million successive table/index-scans of your data will take a while to run, as presumably the source has at least that many records as well. That yields at least 625 trillion (in Europe, billion) reads which even modern hardware will struggle to perform.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - who says that each value requires a separate scan?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: It doesn't of course; you are spoiling the joke with facts. My point was only that 25 million comparison values is probably more than the engine is really prepared to handle.

Comment: thanks for the post! I was just curious, and I was not able to find a similar question and answer anywhere